# Ansible - создание директории с именем и временем создания и последующей записью в неё

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой задачей - создать директорию, где к имени привязывается текущее вермя и дата, к примеру: test_2018-21-11--20-18-05 (создается локально), а потом в эту директорию надо скачать некоторые файлы с удаленного хоста и заархивировать. Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/halberom/b452df40828839fecabf

Answer (score 0):

Описано как-то невнятно. Что-такое "--20-18-05 **(создается локально)**" -  непонятно. Но если надо создать файл с датой и временем создания в имени, то примерно так:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S"
os.mkdir("test_"+now.strftime(fmt))
```

Скачивание с хоста - задача совершенно обычная.
Для архивирования используется модуль zipfile.

Comment: Окей, как ваш ответ использовать в Ansible?

Comment: Думаю, если автора интересует исключительно как это сделать в Ansible то не стоило ставить метку Python

Comment: Ansible написан на Python и позволяет использовать модули Python. А вот как это делать, вы не рассказали, что не есть хорошо